# Rates of change between $x = 2$ and $x = 2 + h$ for $x^2$ and $1/x$

Tags: calculus

What is the simplified average rate of change between $x = 2$ and $x = 2 + h$ for the function:
(Enter your expression as you would enter an equation in Winplot)

a. $f(x) = x^2= 4+h$

b. $(x) = \frac{1}{x}= \frac{-1}{4+2h}$

Are my solutions right?

Comment: How is $x^2=4+h$?

Comment: Does $-1/4+2h$ mean $-\frac14+2h$ or $-1/(4+2h)$?

Comment: The second one. i'm not sure how to format yet

Comment: This [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Kate.K You can accept an answer by clicking the icon to the left. It's a good idea because it takes the question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are correct, but your notation is incorrect.

The average rate of change between $x$ and $x + h$ is 
$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$
When $x = 2$, we obtain
$$\frac{f(2 + h) - f(2)}{h}$$
Your answers should be equal to the latter expression rather than $f(x)$.

> Find the average rate of change for $f(x) = x^2$ between $x = 2$ and $x = 2 + h$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(2 + h) - f(h)}{h} & = \frac{(2 + h)^2 - 2^2}{(2 + h) - 2}\\
                          & = \frac{4 + 4h + h^2 - 4}{h}\\
                          & = \frac{4h + h^2}{h}\\
                          & = 4 + h
\end{align*}
You cannot write that $f(x) = x^2 = 4 + h$.

> Find the average rate of change for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ between $x = 2$ and $x = 2 + h$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{f(2 + h) - f(h)}{h} & = \frac{\dfrac{1}{2 + h} - \dfrac{1}{2}}{(2 + h) - 2}\\
                          & = \frac{\dfrac{2}{2(2 + h)} - \dfrac{2 + h}{2(2 + h)}}{h}\\
                          & = \frac{-\dfrac{h}{2(2 + h)}}{h}\\
                          & = -\frac{h}{2(2 + h)} \cdot \frac{1}{h}\\
                          & = -\frac{1}{2(2 + h)}\\
                       & = -\frac{1}{4 + 2h}
\end{align*}
However, you cannot write $(x) = \frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{4 + 2h}$.